# Android App is not compatible with your device android studio

Tags: android, google-play

I have published and which is showing error on latest version mobiles 
[image]

here is my app build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

 minSdkVersion 17
 targetSdkVersion 28
```

buid.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Where i am going wrong? i want to update my app which will show on every latest version of mobile

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski can u tell me what is the issue?

Comment: show full manifest

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJuL6UBRZWSvqW2dBOJHWqwodAaSo0eY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you really need to list the compatible screens? We never listed ones, and everything is OK for our apps.

Comment: yeah i have tried first build without these screen supported code but getting same issue, for second update i have placed these line. please tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: what is your device, that isn't supported?

Comment: huawei p20 lite
and when i publish apk on developer console it shows warning that 600+ devices can't see your app
i don't know why my targeted sdk is highest i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188338/discussion-between-mudassar-shaheen-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 0):

Using compatible-screens is nearly always a mistake and Google Play ([and the documentation for compatible screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element)) advises against it.

> **Caution**: Normally, **you should not use this manifest element**. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and densities.